# Code fails randomly, 1 iteration it works the next is doesn't with no pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to sort 1 sheet into 6 other sheets based on a couple criteria.

First criteria - does the number have a sub-number. i.e. does 6002 have sub-number 6002A based on column A, copy both original and sub to sheet 1.

Second criteria - if first criteria does not apply does the job have 1 of 2 special categories (5 & 6) based on column Q. if so copy to Sheet 6.

Third Criteria - if the first 2 criteria do not apply which of 4 statuses does it have based on column C, with each going to it's own sheet, sheets 2 thru 5.

The list looks like this:

Col A .... Col C ..............Col Q

6002 ..... status 1 ......... category 5

6003 ..... status 2 ......... category 2

6003A ... status 3 ......... category 2

6003B .... status 3 ........ category 2

6004 ..... status 1 ......... category 1

The issue I am having is that the code only works some of the time. 50% of the time the line: NumLength1 = Len(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value) returns a length of zero even though it is at least 4. When the error happens all 600 or so rows will all fail and be added to sheet 1. when it works all 600 or so rows will be sorted correctly between the 6 sheets.

```
Sub Sorter()
Dim FirstNumber As Long
Dim SecondNumber As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ColumnA As Range
Dim NumLength1 As Integer
Dim NumLength2 As Integer
Dim GetNumber1 As Long
Dim GetNumber2 As Long

   With Worksheets("report_job")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
l = 1
m = 1
n = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells.Clear

    With Sheets("report_job")
        For FirstNumber = 2 To LastRow
        
            NumLength1 = Len(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value)
            
            For g = 1 To NumLength1
                If (IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value, g, 1))) Then result = result & Mid(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value, g, 1)
            Next g
            
            GetNumber1 = result
            result = Empty
            
            For h = 1 To NumLength1
                If (IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(FirstNumber + 1, 1).Value, h, 1))) Then result = result & Mid(Cells(FirstNumber + 1, 1).Value, h, 1)
            Next h
            
            GetNumber2 = result
            result = Empty
            
                If GetNumber1 = GetNumber2 Or Len(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value) > Len(GetNumber1) Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
                        i = i + 1
                    GetNumber1 = Empty
                    GetNumber2 = Empty
                Else
                    If .Cells(FirstNumber, 3).Value = "Status1" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category5" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category6" Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)
                        j = j + 1
                    ElseIf .Cells(FirstNumber, 3).Value = "Staus2" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category5" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category6" Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & k)
                        k = k + 1
                    ElseIf .Cells(FirstNumber, 3).Value = "Status3" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category5" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category6" Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & l)
                        l = l + 1
                    ElseIf .Cells(FirstNumber, 3).Value = "Status4" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category5" And .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value <> "Category6" Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & m)
                        m = m + 1
                    ElseIf .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value = "Category5" Or .Cells(FirstNumber, 17).Value = "Category6" Then
                        .Rows(FirstNumber).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A" & n)
                        n = n + 1
                    End If
                End If
            GetNumber1 = Empty
            GetNumber2 = Empty
        Next FirstNumber
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `With` statement, your references need to start with the `.` character. Otherwise your code will refer to whatever sheet is active, instead of `"report_job"`. The `.` is missing from the `Cells` references several times throughout the code

Instead of:

```
NumLength1 = Len(Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value)
```

use:

```
NumLength1 = Len(.Cells(FirstNumber, 1).Value)
```

And make the same change to the rest of the code.